# Check if an object has a key and it's value is not 0 Javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a scenario where I want to show data of an object based on certain conditions:
Here's my Object data:

```
"charges": {
  "main": "28",
  "extra": "0",
  "extra_01": "806.59",
  "Others": "-230"
}
```

This is how I'm showing this data in my template:

```
<% _.each(model.get("charges"),function(item,key) { %>
      <% if(parseInt(item)) { %>
      <section>
        <span>
          <%=key %>
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right">
          $<%= model.getFormattedAmount(item) %>
          </span>
      </section>
      <% } %>
      <% }); %>
```

So now I've to put a check if there is **bpp** and **not 0**, then show only **bpp** and **Others**.
Else have to show extra stuff like **extra** and **extra_01**. 
To check if **bpp** exists, I've done something like this:

```
var exist = _.has(model.get("charges"), 'bpp');
```

Can anyone please suggest what is the right way to go about it? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
if(model.get("charges").bpp){
  // value exists
  // not 0
  // not false
  // not Null
  // not undefined
  // not ""
  // not NaN
};
```

Comment: Hopefully it is `0` and not `"0"` or this will not work

Comment: @epascarello I personality hate those backend developers who sends numeric data as string to frontend :)